# javascript file type check is empty on windows files

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I'm downloading a JSON file then uploading it and checking the type to be sure its JSON. I'm checking the actual file extension as well as the file type. The extension check works fine but the type check is empty on windows machines:

```
$("[id$='uploadFile']")[0].files[0].type==='application/json'
```

Any idea why this works fine on macs but not windows? For now I'm just leaving in the extension check.